# Search-index npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, leveldb

I am currently working on a Javascript project where I want to use search-index to search through an array of different js objects.
It works, however, it keeps track of all the the previous search result in a level DB database in the main directory.

I dont want that, as the user is only going to be interested in the most recent search results.
Thank you to anyone who can help by providing a way for me to clear the data base after each search, or provide something similar to search-index.

The basic structure of the object I am trying to search is below. My main problem is the fact that each object has its own unique pathway to text and I would like to search each pathway for text, which is what search-index does.

```
    [{ dmodule: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { dmodule: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { dmodule: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { dmodule: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { dmodule: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { dmodule: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { dmodule: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { dml: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], dmlContent: [Object] } },

  { pm: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { pm: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { pm: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } },

  { pm: { identAndStatusSection: [Object], content: [Object] } }]
```

Comment: As of v3 you have `flush` that will do that I think. Here's a test that you may use as an example: https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index/blob/master/test/src/FLUSH-test.js